# Authentication to create route Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model, called `rides`, which I want to have access to my custom token authentication. I *do not* want this to be a made public to the whole viewset.

How can I add the authentication method to the create method? The below throws an error complaining I can't add a `list_route` to a `create` method as it exists already.

```
class RideViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

# POST /rides/
@list_route(methods=['post'], authentication_classes=[CustomTokenAuth])
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: You will agree that a pythong question is meaningless unless properly indendented. Secondly your code extract is far too short (for example what's @list_route?) thirdly you need to include the stack trace

Comment: @e4c5 im sorry-i just switched from ruby to pytho. I'll indent next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decorator won't work on the `ViewSet`'s `list` / `create` / ...

You'll need to deal with the authenticate by yourself.
Therefore you need to fill the DRF's request with:

- `request._authenticator` as the auth backend that has been doing the auth
- `request.user`, `request.auth` as the result of your auth backend's `authenticate()`

Comment: how would this work in practice. `if request.auth:` and then have my method body below it ?